# designing a database schema for aws mobile backend

Tags: sql, database, amazon-web-services, database-design, nosql

I am new to databases and sql and would like to design a database for a fitness app that will keep track of workouts at the gym.

In my app, I have designed a custom workout object that has a name (e.g. 'Chest day'), an ID (some number) and a date (string). Each workout object contains an array of exercises, another custom object, that has a property for called 'set'. The set is also a custom object with only two numeric properties: number of reps and weight (e.g. 10 reps at 50 lbs)

What I thought of is to have one table for the workouts, another for the exercises and another for the sets. The problem is I do not know how to connect the tables (i.e. link multiple exercises to a unique workout and link multiple sets to a unique exercise) and am not sure if this is even the correct approach.

Also, I planned to set up the backend for this app using the amazon web services mobile hub which provides a noSQL database.

Comment: Are you going to use a NoSQL database or a Relational database? That decision directly affects your schema. NoSQL doesn't require a fixed schema but does require a well thought out data model.

Comment: I think I will go with NoSQL. Also I edited my question because I described my model incorrectly

Answer (score 0):

In NoSQL, you should keep all the attributes in single table. You shouldn't normalize the data like RDBMS. Also, please try to come away from Join. The main advantage of NoSQL is that keep everything as one item, so that you don't need to `Join` to get the result.

**Advantages of this approach are:-**

1) Fast response as all the data is present as one item in a table

2) Schema less database i.e. you can add any attributes at any time (i.e. no need to alter table and add the new columns)

**DynamoDB design for above use case:-**

The combination of partition and sort key should be unique

- name -String (Partition Key)
- id -Number (Sort Key)
- date - String
- exercise : [array of values]   - List data type
- custom_set : {rep : 1, weight : 2} - Map data type

**Important Note:-**

The important thing while designing the data model for DynamoDB is all the data retrieval use cases (i.e. Query Access Patterns) should be available to design the appropriate model.